# How can I check if two values in c# are equal? (Given any type of value)

Tags: c#, types, equals

I have this code here, which is intended to allow any type of arguments:

```
public static void AreEqual(object expectedValue, object actualValue) {
    if (expectedValue == actualValue) {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Equal");
    } else {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Not Equal");
    }
}
```

If I call it using a couple of ints it does not behave very well.

```
AreEqual(3, 3)   // prints Not Equal
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At the simplest level:

```
public static void AreEqual(object expectedValue, object actualValue) {
    if (object.Equals(expectedValue,actualValue)) {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Equal");
    } else {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Not Equal");
    }
}
```

Or with generics (supports `IEquatable<T>`):

```
public static void AreEqual<T>(T expectedValue, T actualValue) {
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(expectedValue,actualValue)) {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Equal");
    } else {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Not Equal");
    }
}
```

Comment: so does that mean you get like 10 populist badges at once? lol

Comment: I don't have *any* populist badges ;-(. The "other" answer needs to be +10 too, I believe. So I guess you need +22 or someting!

Answer (score 4):

Just to highlight the reason for the "strange" behavior is because when you cast an int to object [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx) occurs. The two 3s are converted to objects and then you are not comparing numbers anymore, you are comparing references, which will not be the same.

Answer (score 3):

To check if the two object values are equal use this:

```
if (Object.Equals(expectedValue, actualValue)) {
```

As the normal == operator assumes an `object` is a reference type (despite the fact that value types also descend from objects).

Comment: There is no 'normal == operator'. In your method you've told the compiler to treat your arguments as the base object type. When you pass value types into your method, the value type is boxed and the object == operator does compare as references. Both 3's are boxed to different objects, and a reference equality check does correctly indicate the references are not equal.

Comment: You do not need to add the type prefix, Equals is good enough  :)

Comment: I beg to differ, i think most people would consider == is the "normal" equals. Why isn't the compiler smart enough to notice they are both value types and unbox the objects when comparing, isn't that exactly what it does when comparing nullable types?

BTW I answered my own question here because had i spent a lot of time searching for it and couldn't figure it out, so i wanted to contribute a Q&A here. Then some bright spark gave a better answer so that's why i accepted it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (expectedValue.Equals(actualValue))
```

and of course you need to handle `null`, so you should try this:

```
Boolean eq = false;
if (expectedValue == null || actualValue == null)
    eq = (expectedValue == actualValue);
else
    eq = expectedValue.Equals(actualValue);

if (eq) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Equal");
} else {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Not Equal");
}
```

This is of course the same as [@mike nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23616/mike-nelson)'s answer:

```
if (Object.Equals(expectedValue, actualValue))
```

so go upvote his answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
if (expectedValue != null)
{
    if (expectedValue.Equals(actualValue))
    {
        // enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a bad idea... what if expectedValue==null?

Comment: This must be the fastest downvoted accepted answer I've seen so far :)

Comment: So happy I am sober and didn't accidentally leave a wrong answer on this one. wow